# Animate Pandas Dataframe 3D matplot with FuncAnimation

Tags: python, animation, pandas, matplotlib

I have a 3D plot that I'd like to animate, basically add a row from the data frame at a time so I can see the path an object is following.

Here's my static 3D plot:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import pandas as pd

from_csv = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=' ', header=None, names=['x','y','z'], dtype='float')
from_csv.head()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.plot(from_csv['x'], from_csv['y'], from_csv['z'], label='Plot')
plt.show()
```

file.txt looks like this:

```
-33087 -23512 -22237
-33550 -22775 -22700
-32325 -23950 -22087
-33550 -23062 -21787
-33087 -24100 -22550
-33250 -22175 -23312
-32325 -23662 -23012
```

Is there an easy way with `FuncAnimation` to animate the data above so that it shows (appends) one row at a time?